# How to upload a file from Salesforce to Google drive?

Tags: integration, salesforce, google-docs-api, toolkit

Is it possible to upload a file, pdf or word, from a web application made in Salesforce to a Google drive?
I have downloaded the integration toolkit for Google. I can create the file but I am not able to upload the file.
How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to integrate your web application with the Drive SDK as described in the docs: https://developers.google.com/drive/apps_overview

I don't know the Salesforce integration toolkit for Google, but there are complete Drive SDK sample apps in different programming languages at https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/index

Comment: You might want to look at using the REST HTTP protocol directly as you may find it difficult to install a client library into Salesforce. For example here is the API call for inserting files into Google Drive https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files/insert

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem is that my application is wrote in Apex and i cannot use the Java or PHP code. My idea was of store data in Google drive and solve the problem in this way, but the HttpRequest and HttpResponse in Apex do not support the content type : application/pdf or the application/zip and the maximum size of a single request is of 3 MB.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do that. In fact I had done an implementation on the Force.com platform where users could actually upload files to their bucket of space on the Google Drive.

I have started a blog ([integration-of-google-drive-into-force-com](http://theforcetimes.wordpress.com/2012/12/15/integration-of-google-drive-into-force-com/)) just a few days ago and through which I am planning to pass on all my experiments that I would do the Force.com platform to every one around.

I have given a detailed description of the same on my blog. You can visit the same and do approach me for doubts and clarifications.